# Rabbitmq - V6.0.0 - Could not load type 'RabbitMQ.Client.NetworkConnection'

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-standard

Getting Runtime error when using the latest version of
MassTransit and Mass Transit RabbitMQ

Work Around
It resolved when degraded the RabbitMq client to V5.1.2

Does anyone have an idea about this?

Thanks

Comment: Hi,

it is related with: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit/issues/1826

Comment: Thanks @MiguelCosta

Answer (score 2):

It Resolved when degraded the RabbitMq client to V5.1.2

Thanks